# How to Scrape "https://shopee.co.id/search?keyword=phone" with goutte library in laravel?

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, goutte

I want to get value from my code below, but the result is empty.

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Goutte\Client;

class ScrapeController extends Controller
{
    private $results = array();

    public function scraper(){
        $client = new Client();
        $raw = $client->request('GET', 'https://shopee.co.id/search?keyword=phone');
        $raw->filter('.col-xs-2-4')->each(function ($item) {
            $this->results[$item->filter('._1nHzH4')->text()] = $item->filter('_32hnQt')->text();
            
        });
        return $this->results;
    }
}
```

this code cant work. Anyone can give me the solution?

Comment: the HTML returned by `https://shopee.co.id/search?keyword=phone` does not have any elements with that class name - the elements are created dynamically (using javascript loaded in that html document) - does your code evaluate and run the javascript - if not, then you can't scrap that site that easily

Comment: @JaromandaX oke i see. but if that is a dynamic element, how can i get the real element?

Comment: I didn't say IT is a dynamic element (whatever IT is) ... I said those elements that you look for are created dynamically, they are "real", just not in the HTML document you are GETing

Comment: @JaromandaX yeah i know that.  i just want to get the price and the title of product, but i cant found where the class or id that i can use as a filter object.

Comment: because it's not there, as I've said twice now

Answer (score 1):

Use Guzzle HTTP client to make outgoing request from Laravel application.

```
private $results = array();

public function scraper(){
    $client = new Client();
    $guzzleClient = new GuzzleClient(array());
    $client->setClient($guzzleClient);
    //then make request
    $raw = $client->request('GET', 'https://shopee.co.id/search?keyword=phone');
    $raw->filter('.col-xs-2-4')->each(function ($item) {
        $this->results[$item->filter('._1nHzH4')->text()] = $item->filter('_32hnQt')->text();
        
    });
    return $this->results;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is happening because the content of the page is loading via javascript if you want to **scrape** the page you need to execute javascript first with a tool like [phantomjs](https://phantomjs.org/) or use the php library https://github.com/jonnnnyw/php-phantomjs.
so in your case the steps will be:
1: execute javascript using phantomjs and get the raw HTML
2: pass the HTML to the goutte and then filter the data

Comment: sorry, does phantomjs must use laravel 5 or 6 ? because when i always get error when installing phantom with composer

Comment: I dont know exactly but v6 or 7 should be fine

Comment: can i get some source to read? because i have been trying, but when i try to type composer require "jonnyw/php-phantomjs:4.*" in terminal, i always getting error "Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages."